# Integral and Cauchy theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Question : Compute the integral of 
$$
\int^{2 \pi}_0 \frac{1}{3+2\cos t}dt.
$$
Indication: take the path $\gamma: [0,2 \pi] \to \mathbb{C}$, $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$ and the integral of 
$$
\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z^2+3z+1} dz.
$$

I am stucked on this problem since a good while. Is there someone who could solve this problem for me?

Thanks!

Comment: $$\cos t = \frac{1}{2}\left(e^{it} + \frac{1}{e^{it}}\right)$$ Make the substitution they suggested and massage it a bit to get the second integral, then break the integrand into two pieces with partial fractions, and finally integrate.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I'm curious to see a complete answer using your index. Could you show a complete response?

Comment: @george Someone else can fill in the details, but I pretty much gave a perfect guide to follow.

Comment: @CameronWilliams The integral I have to do is an real integral; so $\cos t$ is the real cosinus and not the complex cosinus as you consider in your previous sending

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760520/int2-pi-0-frac1-sqrt5-cos-tdt-int2-pi-0-frac-cos2t-5

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is a real integral. The basic idea here is to convert the real integral into a complex one and make it a contour integral.

Since the bounds are 0 to 2pi we can use the unit circle as the contour.

The the following substitutions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now make these subs and factor the integrand. Now look for poles inside the unit circle and use residue theorem on them.

Comment: Would you be able to do the whole integral?